# Why can't I use the onchange event in input type = "number"

Tags: javascript, php, html, onchange

```html
<input type="number" 
      min="1" max="99" 
      value="<?php echo $value['num']; ?>" 
      id="bang_<?php echo $key ?>" 
      onchange="cartup(<?php echo $key; ?>)">
```

I have a problem when I change the value of the input box, it immediately causes an error and I don't know what is the error

> **error: cart.php:409 Uncaught ReferenceError: cartup is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange (cart.php:409)**

Comment: You are probably missing the quotes inside cartup. Try `onchange="cartup('<?php echo $key; ?>')"`

Comment: Where did you define `cartup`?

Comment: The error suggests that the function `cartup()` is not defined in your javascript. Maybe check your script again for a misspelling of the function, or something like that? Or add your javascript to the question so that we can have a look.

Comment: ```function cartup(id){

num = $("#bang_"+id).val();
alert(num);
}``` this is my cartup

Comment: Is cartup() defined later in the code?

Comment: Where is the js code inserted? (so html can access it)